# Reading GPS data from a gadget

Tags: c++, gps

I have a GPS gadget, and I would like to know how I can receive information with C++ (coordinates) from it?

Comment: At the very least you need to specify which make/model you're using.

Comment: -1: Sorry, but this question is unanswerable. What gadget (make/model)? How does it connect to computer (USB, Serial, Bluetooth, Wifi)? What platform are you running on (Windows, Unix, Max, Linix)?

Answer (score 5):

This is *probably* easier to answer than the comments indicate. While most GPS units *do* support proprietary (usually) binary protocols, nearly all that are even close to current also support NMEA-formatted data, and will supply it by default. Whether connected by serial port, bluetooth or USB, most also look to user programs like a serial port.

IOW, you can probably support something like 90% of reasonably current GPS units simply by opening a serial port, and reading data from it. The only ugly part is that the [NMEA standard](http://www.nmea.org/content/nmea_standards/nmea_2000_ed2_20.asp) for the data format is fairly expensive (though it's not as bad as it used to be -- you can now buy just the parts of it you care about, which is to say only appendix B, IIRC).

Fortunately, unless you're planning to get your software certified for marine or aircraft navigation, you probably don't need that -- there are a fair number of [web sites](http://home.mira.net/~gnb/gps/nmea.html) that cover the (few) message types you probably care about. For that matter, if you just open up a terminal program on the right COM port and look at the data, it's not too hard to find the latitude/longitude all by yourself (at least if you have at least a vague notion of where you are).

It's *basically* CSV format -- one record per line, with fields separated by commas. It's all in normal ASCII/ANSI text, so getting coordinates is mostly a matter of checking that the first field says it's the right kind of record ("$GPGGA"), then getting fields 3, 4 5, and 6 (3 and 4 are latitude and 5 and 6 longitude -- 3 and 5 give the number, 4 and 6 have "N", or "S" and "E" or "W" to indicate north/south latitude and East/West longitude). You'll probably also want to check that the field after that contains "1" or "2", indicating a normal or Differential GPS fix respectively (a "0" would indicate no GPS fix, so invalid data).

Not that it matters a lot, but you should probably also realize that there are several other field types you'll probably receive, and some of them contain fix data as well. $GPGGA just happens to be the one I've used -- there are others that are probably just as good, but I've never had much reason to look at others, because that one's been adequate for what I needed/did.

Edit: Here's a sample dump of data *exactly* as it's received from the GPS, in this case over a Bluetooth virtual serial port:

$GPGGA,090809.103,3901.4345,N,10448.2482,W,0,00,50.0,2078.2,M,-21.4,M,0.0,0000*43
$GPRMC,090809.103,V,3901.4345,N,10448.2482,W,0.00,0.00,220311,,*07
$GPVTG,0.00,T,,M,0.00,N,0.0,K*60
$GPGGA,090810.103,3901.4345,N,10448.2482,W,0,00,50.0,2078.2,M,-21.4,M,0.0,0000*4B

In the second $GPGGA record:

$GPGGA,090810.103,3901.4345,N,10448.2482,W,0,00,50.0,2078.2,M,-21.4,M,0.0,0000*4B

"$GPGGA" is the record ("Sentence") type identifier.
"090810.103" is the current UTC time.
"3901.4345,N" is the latitude.
"10448.2482,W" is the longitude.
The next: "0" is telling you that the preceding latitude/longitude are *not* valid.

The latitude and longitude are both formatted (IIRC) with the last two places *before* the decimal point being the minutes, and what's after the decimal point the fractions of a minute, so the `3901.4345" really means 39º 1.4345' north latitude.

Comment: But, isn't NMEA data is something related to info about satellite? As i understand GPS devices recieves NMEA data and counts the probable area by triangulation? Or NMEA data is exectly what i need?

Comment: @KAGDGAP: NMEA data does contain data about what satellites the GPS is receiving data from at the moment, but the GPS does the triangulation itself, so the NMEA data will contain latitude and longitude (and altitude, speed, heading, etc.) I'll edit some sample data into the answer.

Comment: @KAGDGAP, the GPS does not receive NMEA from satellites.  It generates it itself.  The one you want is the *recommended minimum sentence* or GPRMC.  See http://www.codepedia.com/1/The+GPRMC+Sentence