# Algorithm to convert location coordinates from DD.DDDDD format to DDMM.MMMMM

Tags: objective-c, coordinates, core-location, coordinate-systems

I'm making an app which uses CoreLocation to provide GPS coordinates. The next thing I need is to convert the coordinates from the `dd.ddddd` format to `ddmm.mmmmm` format and I don't have a clue how to make that.

Google didn't help me a lot either.

Comment: The ddmm.mmm looks like NMEA format.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5388625/467105) should give you enough info to write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on Wikipedia at: [Geographic coordinate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)